# Are there any major differences between OpenCobol and NetExpress Microfocus Cobol?

Tags: cobol, gnucobol, microfocus

I am taking a course in COBOL this semester and just got the syllabus, which requires the NetExpress Microfocus COBOL compiler.  I'd rather use OpenCobol though, so I can stay on Linux or OS X.

Are there any major differences between the two compilers that might get in the way, or that I should know about before going in to the class with this plan?

ps. I know I should ask the professor, and plan to, but I'd like to see if anyone has any ideas to see if maybe I can just minimize my time in a vm.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you avoid vendor extensions -- and you should if you are just learning the language -- you should see no difference in the way the two process ANS COBOL.